# ModuleNotFoundError and ImportError when trying to import can package

Tags: python, windows, pip, importerror, modulenotfounderror

When I try to run code with imported can package

```py
import can 
from can.interfaces.vector import canlib
from datetime import datetime
```

I get an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'can.interfaces'; 'can' is not a package.
```

My interpreter path is global [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lURyJ.png) and packages are installed in the C:\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages. What might cause the problem? I'm using Windows 10.

EDIT

I changed file name from can.py to other and it works (thanks FlyingTeller), but now I get another error when trying to import can module.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\__work__\DownloadFiles_Karol\nweasdawd.py", line 2, in <module>
    from can.interfaces.vector import canlib
  File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\can\interfaces\vector\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .canlib import VectorBus, VectorChannelConfig
  File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\can\interfaces\vector\canlib.py", line 39, in <module>
    from can import BusABC, Message, CanInterfaceNotImplementedError, CanInitializationError
ImportError: cannot import name 'BusABC' from 'can' (C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\can\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Please post the code and error as text not an images.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a
question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have named your file `can`, so it is shadowing the import that you want. Rename it to something else

Comment: Hey, your solution has helped me, but now I get another error - "ImportError: cannot import name 'BusABC' from 'can' (C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\can\__init__.py)". Can you help me with that? It is strange because it does work for me at another computer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This happens when you simply do `import can`?

Comment: Yes, I will update my post soon

Comment: Post is edited now.

Comment: I don't know what is causing the other issue though

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I uninstalled both can and python-can.

I then reinstalled only python-can.

Turns out they try to install into the same folder.